# Javascript get status from service

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, cross-domain

I develop a web application that is getting user updates from a web service (that is in another domain) I want to get the updates every 10 seconds.

For calling the service for the first time I dynamically insert a script in the page. The service is JSONP. Then I would like to define a trigger that insert a script from 10 to 10 seconds to get the updates. Is this correct? Can I do that without affecting the user experience on the website? I mean the site performance ... it will be great if I could do the call async and when I have the results I will update the status.

Is there any better solution for accessing the remote services. Is there an efficient way of dynamically reusing the same script using a trigger? I am pretty new to Javascript. Can you give me a short sample how can I define a trigger that calls a remote web service? ... or if there is a better solution.

Comment: Although not widely supported, a `WebSocket` can have a 'live' connection between the server and a client, thus enabling you to send data from/to the server immediately. And the bandwidth is less since you're not firing requests every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will dynamically create the script tags, and delete them (and the global it requires) after being finished with a given call.

You could also use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) to allow requests besides GET ones, though as you may be aware, that is not supported in older browsers.

To avoid race conditions or performance problems during a slow network, you could allow the JSONP callback to recursively call the function, thereby only making a new call if the callback was returned, though with an optional `setTimeout` call to ensure there is at least a minimum delay.

The following uses Wikipedia's API to grab a specific page revision and its user.

```
<script>
var JSONP = function(global){
    // (C) WebReflection Essential - Mit Style ( http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/02/all-you-need-for-jsonp.html )
    // 202 bytes minified + gzipped via Google Closure Compiler
    function JSONP(uri, callback) {
        function JSONPResponse() {
            try { delete global[src] } catch(e) { global[src] = null }
            documentElement.removeChild(script);
            callback.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        var
            src = prefix + id++,
            script = document.createElement("script")
        ;
        global[src] = JSONPResponse;
        documentElement.insertBefore(
            script,
            documentElement.lastChild
        ).src = uri + "=" + src;
    }
    var
        id = 0,
        prefix = "__JSONP__",
        document = global.document,
        documentElement = document.documentElement
    ;
    return JSONP;
}(this);

// Be sure to include the callback parameter at the end

function startAPI (start) {
    start = start || new Date();
    var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Main%20Page&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content&format=json&callback';
    var minimum = 10000;
    function execute (str) {
        alert(str);
    }
    JSONP(url, function (obj) {
        for (var pageNo in obj.query.pages) {
            var page = obj.query.pages[pageNo];
            var str = 'The user ' + page.revisions[0]['user'] + ' left the page with this code ' + page.revisions[0]['*'];
            execute(str);
            var elapsed = (new Date().getTime()) - start;
            setTimeout(startAPI, (elapsed < minimum) ? (minimum - elapsed) : 0);
            break;
        }
    });
}
startAPI(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that in your AJAX callback, when you get the result, you schedule a timer (`window.setTimeout(ex, t)`) so that your updating script is called again.

The reason to set the time in the AJAX callback is that you don't know exactly how long it will take for the AJAX call to complete. In this way, you ensure a smooth 10 sec delay between successive updates.

About performance, you will have to check that. It depends on the amount of data and the kind of processing you do of it (and the rest of your page)... but you can try it and check processor usage...

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of JavaScript's `setInterval` method

```
function getUpdate () {
    //AJAX goes here
}

var myInterval = setInterval(getUpdate,10000);
```

This way you'll need to inject the script-tag only once.